# iOS 11 [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ignoring [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

Tags: ios

When I launch my app, I set my default timezone to GMT
`[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];`

Then, on subsequent calls to `[NSTimeZone]`, I use `-localTimeZone`. Until iOS 10, everything worked properly and I got GMT-0 as the returned timezone. Now, on iOS 11, I get my localtime, which is GMT-3.

Also, if I call `-defaultTimeZone` instead, I also get GMT-0, which is the right answer. Someone nows why `-localTimeZone` changed its behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in iOS11. I filed a radar it's marked by Apple as "DUPLICATE OF 33629367"(still an open issue as of iOS11.1 beta). In most cases it's best to stop using localTimeZone... it is a bit of a threading nightmare.

How things are supposed to work:

- [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] returns the system timezone always. If the system timezone changes then you have to requery this method(the NSTimeZone returned doesn't autoupdate)
- [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] returns systemTimeZone unless a defaultTimeZone has been set. If the default or system timezones change then you have to requery this method(the NSTimeZone returned doesn't autoupdate)
- [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] returns a timezone equal to what defaultTimeZone returns. The NSTimeZone returned DOES autoupdate if systemTimeZone or defaultTimeZone change. So it could update on you in the middle of a function.

In iOS11, [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] seems to be equivalent to [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]